# Hobgoblin, hobnail, hobnob

Tags: meaning, prefixes

I would like to know if "hob" can be considered as a prefix, and if yes,  does it have some meaning, at least vague? I am thinking in particular about words hobgoblin, hobnail, hobnob...

Comment: It's General Reference (if you check an etymological dictionary) that all three examples here have *different* origins for the ***hob*** component. In ***hobgoblin*** it's a diminutive of *Robin [Goodfellow]*. In ***hobnail***, it's  obscure, but probably related to *hub [part of a fireplace/stove]*. And ***hobnob*** is a weird reduplication apparently based on (or at least, *meaning* something like) *have/not have, give and take*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It’s certainly not General Reference for an English language learner to go researching and comparing etymologies, but I’ll join you in your close-vote since etymology is itself generally off-topic here.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about etymology and would perhaps be better suited for [ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I don't see that this is off-topic; the poster noticed a possible prefix and couldn't figure out whether it was a real, productive prefix or not.  Seems like a good question to me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Fun question!

In general, "hob" shouldn't be considered one prefix. In the first two cases you list, "hob" is actually two different prefixes. The "hob" in "hobgoblin" is a colloquial synonym for "Robert".  The "hob" in "hobnail" comes from the term for a blunt projection of some sort

In the third case, I don't believe "hob" is a prefix at all, since "hobnob" is a combination of two verbs. Here, "hob" comes from the verb "to have."

Source: comparison of etymological dictionary entries for each word (in particular [etymonline.com](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=hobgoblin))

Comment: Where did you come up with this? Completely incorrect.  A hob is part of a stove and leads to all three terms. Hobgoblins were house spirits (*B*ob is short for Robert, not hob). The term then meant rustic which lead to the boots and the biscuit.

Comment: @JamesRyan Here are some sources: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=hobgoblin http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hobgoblin http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/hob#hob-2